# Using Substring Method In Function Breaks Other Strings

Tags: function, powershell

I'm working on a function, which works fine except when I try to use the Substring method.

Once I add .substring(#,#) to any of the strings in my function, other strings seem to break.

Am I doing something wrong? I can't figure out a way to use substring() in a function without it breaking the function.

If I run my code outside of a function, everything seems to work fine.

```
function Get-String ($string1, $string2)
{
    return($string1.substring(0,1) + $string2)
}

Get-String("One"+"Two")
```

I'd expect this function to return "OTwo"
It returns "O"

Replacing the variables with string literals resolves the issue.

Comment: You are concatenating the two strings into one string in the function call. Use `Get-String "One" "Two"` instead. Don't use brackets there, simply state the parameters separated by space.

Comment: Doh! It seems so obvious now. - thanks Theo!

Answer (score 2):

Per Theo's comment:
changed

```
Get-String("One"+"Two")
```

to

```
Get-String "One" "Two"
```

and everything works perfectly now.